# Oracle systimestamp timezone differs from OS timezone

Tags: oracle, operating-system, timezone, centos7

`SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'tzr') FROM dual;` returns -03:00

`date +"%Z"` in OS console returns +03.

Is it possible?

P.S. Oracle version 11.2.0.4.0. OS - CentOS-7.

Comment: It is entirely possible: if the database runs on a different server (different computer) than the one the console is linked to. SYSTIMESTAMP shows the timestamp in the time zone of the host computer running the database **server**, not your client (the program you use to connect to the database, perhaps remotely).

Comment: "Is it possible?" - clearly the answer is "Yes".

Comment: Yes it is possible